# POST JSON string with PHP and CURL to a php page and get response

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I'm trying to learn how to POST a PHP through CURL to another PHP page and read the response.

I have 2 pages.  The first is test.php

```
<?php
$array['User'] = array();
$array['User']['AppId'] = 'sdfgfd9-sdfgsdf-sdfgfdgfgff';
$array['User']['UserName'] = 'me@example.co.uk';
$array['User']['Token'] = 'fsdgf5-455g-223ee-bggg-asdsadsda';
$array['User']['Timestamp'] = '2018-05-30BST16:28:293600';

$url = "https://www.myurl.co.uk/api/index.php";    
$content = json_encode($array['User']);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) 
{
   die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response 
  $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . 
  curl_errno($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
echo $response;
?>
```

Then on the page I'm getting data from I simply have;

```
<?php
$userArray = array();   
$userArray = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo json_decode($userArray, true);
?>
```

When I run the script on test.php the repsonse I'm getting is;

```
Error: call to URL https://www.myurl.co.uk/api/index.php failed with status 200, response Array, curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

I don't understand the error enough to understand what to change to make this work?

Comment: 200 is not an error code, it's a success code.

Comment: Try again with 200 being success, and report the results

Comment: I didn't realise the if statement around the output was incorrect.  It all works perfectly thank you

Answer (score 0):

try:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array(
'method' => 'POST',
'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json' . "\r\n"
. 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string) . "\r\n",
'content' => $data_string,
);

or similar